# How prevent hudi to write patition columns into data?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-hudi

Consider the following:

1. data are read from partitioned structure `y=,m=,d=`.
2. hudi `DataSourceWriteOptions.PARTITIONPATH_FIELD_OPT_KEY` config is set to `y=,m=,d=`

At first glance I have to remove `y,m,d` columns but without these columns hudi will not know about partitions, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is use version `0.9.0`.

[How to drop hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field fields from a Hudi Dataset?](https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/2213)

[Hudi FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HUDI/FAQ#FAQ-Whypartitionfieldsarealsostoredinparquetfilesinadditiontothepartitionpath?)

[Jira task with pull request link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HUDI-1363)

Answer (score 0):

would you please open a github issue to get timely response.